# custom views in LinearLayout with weights - only first object is drawing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-custom-view, custom-view

I'm trying to create a new custom view, and than put some duplicates of that (to be changed later by java, as in custom background etc)

But out of 3 views I put in a linear layout, only the first one is getting drawn.

Tried that with multiple custom views, and it behaves the same - only first view is to be drawn.

Why?

code snippet:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float top = getTop();
        float bottom = getBottom();
        float right = getRight();
        float left = getLeft();
        float width = right - left;
        float height = bottom - top;
        float rectSize = Math.min(width, height)/10;
        float centerX = left + width/2;
        float centerY = top + height/2;

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right,bottom, paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(centerX-rectSize, centerY-rectSize, centerX+rectSize, centerY+rectSize, paint);

    }

}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <com.example.halamishre.myapplication.CustomView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <com.example.halamishre.myapplication.CustomView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            />
        <com.example.halamishre.myapplication.CustomView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />




    </LinearLayout>
```

screenshot:
[image: screenshot of the activity]

Comment: Change width to "0dp"... like android:layout_width="0dp"

Comment: set layout_weightsum 3 in linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

Your Custom view have problem, as You are using weight the getRight() & getLeft() methods are providing same value for all 3 and it is unable to draw remaining two view. Use following code

```
 float top = 0;
 float bottom = getMeasuredHeight;
 float right = getMeasuredWidth();
 float left = 0;
 float width = getMeasuredWidth();
 float height = getMeasuredHeight();
 float rectSize = Math.min(width, height)/10;
 float centerX = width/2;
 float centerY = height/2;
```

Comment: thanks!
can you please clarify this - the view always starts with left=0 and top=0? no matter where it is drawn in the layout?

Answer (score -1):

`layout_weight` of 1 occupies the entire parent. You need to set the `weightSum` to 3 in your case to display all 3 custom views of weight 1. Or you can set each weight to a fraction that will add to 1.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are wrong. try youtself - put 3 Views inside linear layout and assign color background to those views, make them all have same weight and notice they get the same dimentions.